# Can I format email body with Django in App Engine?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, email

I'm trying to understand if I can format the body of an email in app engine with Django.
I have all the website format with Django, but I can't understand if I can do the same with the email.
Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to, assuming you're talking about HTML mails? What happens when you try?

Comment: I can't understand how I can try! Normally I have the .html file with the Django code and I pass all the vars with self.response.out.write((template.render('dapagare.html', {'html':html}))

Comment: Well, you're calling `template.render`. So do exactly the same, except pass it to the email API, rather than writing it to the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can. You do not need HTML files, you can also use .txt files for your templates.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the comment I got the solution:

```
testo = template.render(u'prova.html',{'prova':prova})
mail.send_mail(sender=email, to=email2, subject=oggetto,body=testo)
```